# SFINAE with several condition [Refactoring]

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, sfinae

How can I write this function shorter?

```
template<typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<U>::value>::type,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<char, U>::value>::type,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<void, U>::value>::type
>
void multiply(U&& u){};
```

I want exclude several type like void or char, which don't must be number. I wrote code like this, but I think, that is better solution. (code of course is correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems short enough to me.

It's impossible to know how to refactor any code without first knowing *what it is supposed to do*. All we know about this no-op function is that you "want [to] exclude several type[s] like void or char". How many types? Which types? Why?

---

The obvious shortening is

```
template<class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<U>>,
    class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<char, U> && !std::is_same_v<void, U>>
>
void multiply(U&&) {}
```

i.e. just remove all the superfluous `::type` and `::value`, and replace `typename` by `class` because it's shorter (and you did ask for us to make it shorter!).

---

Your naming the function `multiply` implies that maybe what you want is

```
template<class U>
auto multiply(U&& u) -> decltype(u*u, void()) {}
```

---

Your comments about "don't must be number" imply that maybe what you want is

```
template<class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<U>>>
void multiply(U&&) {}
```

But we really can't know for sure unless you tell us what the code is *supposed* to do.

Comment: I asked only about shorter version, i want know how can i write this code shorter, but thanks for entire answer. ;) It was only example for problem.

Comment: Yeah, but if the *only* criterion is "shortness", why not just replace the whole thing with `void m(){}` or `int i;`? There must be *some* criterion by which we can judge whether a shortening is "reasonable" or not...

Comment: okey i understand.